# Can using a linux bootable USB flash drive be used to circumvent ransomware?

Tags: linux, windows, usb

My system is not infected with ransomware.  I was just thinking about ways to deal with it if it ever happened.  Since I can boot my windows PC with a Linux USB and access the HDD, shouldn't it be possible to use the USB drive to back-up the HDD after ransomware was installed?  Most ransomware uses the browser to lock up the computer, does it not?  All anyone would have to do is boot with a Linux USB and transfer the files from the HDD to an external drive. Then reformat the HDD, reinstall windows and be on their merry way.  Unless BIOS is infected (which is unlikely) there should be no issue, right?

I would just like to know if this is a viable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ransomware encrypt your HDD. So, if you were to boot to your Linux Drive, you will not be able to view the files in your HDD as it is encrypted and you don't know the key. Most common ransomware use your encrypted data as ransom and will only give you the decryption key if you pay them their ransom. So, using a USB drive to save your computer will not work.

However, you should be able to format your drive from the Linux bootable drive, but you will still lose all your data

Comment: Cool, thanks.  However I have to ask;  I run Ubuntu on my laptop and the HDD is encrypted.  I can still boot it off of a Kali USB and access the hard-drive.  Does ransomware have a different kind of encryption or something?

Comment: Although you will be able to mount the drive, you will not be able to see its contents without entering the decryption key. If you are still able to see the contents of your drive without entering the password/key, you have not encrypted the drive properly